# Add tag before and after line in text file using php

Tags: php

I have text file with  lines:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

I need to adding tag before and after text

output

```
<h1>text1</h1>
<h1>text2</h1>
<h1>text3</h1>
```

I'm using this script

```
$file = file_get_contents("test.txt");
$handle = fopen($file);
$output = '';
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)     {
$output .= '<h1>' . $line .'</h1>' . "\n";
}
fclose($handle);
file_put_contents($output, $file);
```

I got this error:

> Warning: fopen() expects at least 2     parameters, 1 given in on line 4
>       Warning: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 7
>       Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in  line 10
>       Warning: file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in  line 11

Comment: have a look to the doc. Just type "php fopen", you'll find php.net, and see expected parameters.

Comment: 1) You are using `file_get/put_contents()` and `fopen()`, while `file_get_contents()` already opens the file 2) Why do you want to save your text with html tags? I would save it without it and if you want to output it just use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `fopen();` function there is a parameter mode, that specifies the type of access you require to the stream, due to this you are getting warnings.. read more about [f_open()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Here i have two methods for you to write in file

**Method 1 :** Using `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`

```
$file = 'test.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$rows = explode("\n", $current);
$output= '';
foreach($rows  as $row)
{
    $output .= '<h1>'.$row.'</h1>'. "\n";
}
file_put_contents($file, $output);
```

**Method :2** Is that your are trying to use

```
$file = 'test.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$handle = fopen($file,'r');
$output = '';
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)    
{
    $output .= '<h1>'. $line .'</h1>'."\n";
}
fclose($handle);
file_put_contents($file, $output);
```

Comment: glad to help you @vallez, vote my answer if, it is useful for you... :)